# why general sibling combinator & adjacent sibling combinator not working for ul + li & tr + td

Tags: html, css

I am new to development, so i am practicing the Html & CSS by watching YouTube

In one of the tutorial video, the tutor is teaching about the advanced selectors. In that he is giving the example for usage of adjacent & general sibling combinator

Ex: h2 + a {}, h2 ~ p {}

when i tried as per above, it worked. So, for practice i tried those on ul + li, tr ~ td, but it didn't worked.

May i know the reason for this?

```css
h2 ~ p {
  color: red;
 }
  ul + li {
  color: purple;
  }
```

```html
 <h2 class="subtitle">About Me</h2>
    
    <img src="../img/img-1.jpg">
    
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. 
    
    Cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla , pariatur:
    
      <ul><!--parent-->
        <li>Excepteur sint occaecat</li><!--first child-->
        <li>My numbered list item</li><!--second child-->
        <li>Nulla excepteur irure</li><!--third child-->
      </ul>
    </p>
```

```css
h2 + a {
  color: red;
  }
  tr ~ td {
    color:green;
    }
```

```html
<h2 class="subtitle" id="subtitle-id">Services</h2>
    
    <a href="http://www.google.com" id="google-link">Click here to go to Google</a>
    
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem</td>
          <td>Ipsum</td>
          <td>Dolor</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Sit</td>
          <td>Amet</td>
          <td>Consectetur</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Adipisicing</td>
          <td>Elit</td>
          <td>Sed</td>
        </tr>
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Are you trying to set css or scss ? As it looks like sccs in your demo.

Comment: It's css only, i am not yet into scss

Comment: I was asking because you are not closing your `h2 + a { color: red;` and directly adding the next elements after that so a `}` is missing.

Comment: ya thanks, i didn't seen that mistake, it's just a typo

Comment: Hi! Ensure your image also has an alt attribute to either provide alt text or mark the image as decorative. You can learn more about alt text here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decision-tree/#:~:text=This%20decision%20tree%20describes%20how,instead%20of%20images%20of%20text.

Answer (score 2):

Siblings are two elements with the same parent.

A list item cannot be a *sibling* of a list, it must be a *child* of a list.

A table data cell cannot be the *sibling* of a table row, it must be a *child* of a table row.

---

a and b are siblings

```
<a></a>
<b></b>
```

c and d are parent and child

```
<c> <d></d> </c>
```